# Getting "S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on this bucket" error when using django-storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

In a Django project that uses [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and is configured with AWS credentials, I am getting the following error when uploading a file (i.e. saving a model that has a `models.FileField` field)

`An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation: S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on this bucket`

I triple-checked the AWS credentials -- they even work on another computer with the same codebase, but not on my machine. (I provide the solution below)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening because my `~/.aws/config` global AWS/boto3 configuration file had:

```
[default]
s3 =
    use_accelerate_endpoint = true
```

This, in turn, was read by the boto3 library (see [this page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) and search for "use_accelerate_endpoint") which then tried to use the accelerated endpoint on an S3 bucket which did not have an accelerated endpoint enabled.